# Meanings of 'furo'

Tags: vocabulary, verbs

I am finding some conflicting information about the word *furo*. According to Lewis and Short, it only means *furo/furere*, a defective 3rd conjugation word meaning to be in a rage. In L&S, only *furor* (steal) is found as a deponent verb.

However, [in some online dictionaries](https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php?lemma=FURO100), it says that *furo/furare* is not a deponent verb but is transitive and means to steal, hide/conceal or escape, and has passive forms (for example, *furatur* = he is hidden).

Is this a case where L&S is referring only to classical Latin, and the online dictionaries have medieval forms or what?

Answer (score 2):

There are two verbs here:
*fūrārī, fūror*
and
*furere, furō*.
There is no verb *furare* in classical Latin as far as I can tell.

We have [a nice list of good online Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79), and I recommend you use them (or some of the top entries there) instead of the one you link to.
The list also includes the comparative tool Logeion, and [it tells you that no dictionary within it knows about a verb *furare, furo*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/furo).
Not all online sources are reliable, and some sources should be dismissed for that reason.

The verb *furari* seems to mean "to steal" and similar things.

The verb *furere* seems to mean "to rage" and similar things.

I don't know where the proposed meanings for *furare* come from.
Perhaps it is a merger of *furari*, *fugere*, and something else.
Perhaps it is a later usage — but if it was common in later Latin, I would expect the print dictionaries I own to mention it and they don't.
Wiktionary hasn't heard of such a word either.
I would simply dismiss that entry, and therefore I would stop trusting that website.